Latin translation of "no slavery beyond death"
How would you say (or express the sentiment of) "no slavery beyond (as in 'after)' death" in Latin?
Thanks!

Here's a suggestion that borrows from Anserin's helpful answer:

mortui nullus est dominus.

This literally means:

A dead man has no master.

If you're more interested in the general sense rather than the specific wording, Seneca has a very relevant section in his 26th letter to Lucilius, where he gives his traditional closing quote. In this case, the quote is from Epicurus:

"Meditare mortem"; qui hoc dicit, meditari libertatem iubet. Qui mori didicit, servire dedidicit; supra omnem potentiam est, certe extra omnem. Quid ad illum carcer et custodia et claustra? Liberum ostium habet.

My translation:

"Reflect on death." He who says this commands us to reflect on freedom. He who has learned how to die has unlearned how to be a slave. This is above every power; indeed, he is beyond every power. What prison, guards, and bars can touch him? His door is open [i.e. free].


Maybe "Nulla servitudo post mortem."?
Nulla - zero, no
servitudo - slavery, from "servus" (slave)
post - after
mortem - accusative singular of "mors" (death), because "post" is followed by accusative

How about adding an explanation of how your translation works and how its meaning compares to the original? You've been told before and I tell you again: A context-free dump is not a very useful answer, even if the Latin is perfect. Compare your answer to the highly voted translation answers on the site and you can't miss the difference.

I'm not sure this grammar is correct; I'm accustomed to a different word order.

@Joshua The word order is fine. I don't know what you're accustomed to, but the only thing that Latin grammar requires is that post comes before mortem and that none of the other words here come between them (a hypothetical adjective modifying mortem would, of course, be allowed to). Apart from that the word order is quite free. It would be OK and not unusual to say Servitudo post mortem nulla. (Reginald Foster is said to have taught by the motto: Dies sine auctoribus nulla (ne prima quidem))
